# Embedding page in sharepoint webpart

Tags: c#, iframe, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I need to create webpart in sharepoint 2010 which will allow me to view page from specific URL.

I.E. I'd like to view http://google.com from this webpart. **What's the simpliest way to accomplish that ?** I'm totally novice to Sharepoint developement, I've just downloaded SDK and watched some screencasts about creating webparts. Also I'd like to have few of this webparts on one page.

Maybe there is another and better way than creating a webpart ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [Page Viewer Webpart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx). It embeds an IFRAME in the page, actually.

Comment: thank you, I should search on google for it first though before asking this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another and better way than showing external pages in an IFrame. Usually something like this will do:

```
This is not actually google, and eventhough we would love to actually be google
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">this link</a> will have to do for now
```

Or if you are serious about displaying data from external partners, you should consider retrieving data through web-services.

Comment: I have my own site with multiple data (presented on user controls), and it's not possible to retrieve that using webservices based on architecture I have right now.